# Cannot create new lists and cannot save places to existing lists in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have three predefined lists in Google Maps (Favorites, Want to go and Starred places). When I try to save any location to the first two I get an error "Failed to save to Favorites" or "Failed to save to Want to go". However, I can save successfully to the Starred places.

Also, when I try to create my own list using "New list" I get a "Failed to create list" error.

The error messages come from the bottom of the page in a dark grey box, like this:

[image]

So, why can't I use these features? This is not a one-time thing, I've been trying to do this for a couple of weeks now and get the same issue.

EDIT: 
Just found out that the feature works when I am connected to the internet via VPN selecting a server in Latvia for example. As soon as I'm disconnected and get back to my local server in Azerbaijan the feature stops working. So it can be a region-based problem maybe?

Comment: How many items are in each list? Is it possible you've run up against a hard limit?

Comment: "Want to go" is empty, "Favorites" has 10 items. So no, it's probably something else.

Comment: Can you create new lists? Maybe something is borked about these.

Comment: No, I mentioned this issue in the post, too: when I try to create my own list using "New list" I get a "Failed to create list" error.

Comment: Well then, I'm flummoxed. The feature's less than a year old; I can't imaging they're looking to kill it now. Maybe it's just a bug? For what it's worth, it seems to be working for me. Try another browser? Network?

Comment: It didn't work on Chrome and Firefox. It does work occasionally at my home network as opposed to my work network where it never works. It is indeed very strange.

Comment: Is there somewhere where I can report this bug if this is indeed a bug? I tried https://productforums.google.com but haven't got a solution yet.

Comment: There's a link to the "Send feedback" tool near the bottom of the main menu. Select that and the "Your opinion about Maps" option. You can even include a screenshot.

Comment: At the time of the feature's launch, it was limited to users with certain "levels" associated with their accounts.  Levels were based on activity and contribution back to Google Maps/other apps in the Google family.  You may want to check your account settings to determine if you have a privacy setting opting you out of the list feature, as well as try commenting on places/updating existing map data.  Also worth trying- can you access/edit your lists from a phone or tablet?

Comment: Just found out that the feature works when I am connected to the internet via VPN selecting a server in Latvia for example. As soon as I'm disconnected and get back to my local server in Azerbaijan the feature stops working. So it can be a region-based problem maybe?

Comment: @AnsonWHan I couldn't find the privacy setting you were referring to. I am able to use this feature using my phone. Also please note my edit re VPN.

Comment: All else fail, you can use Googleearth instead. A bit bulky but all features work

Comment: It could very well be a regional restriction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was indeed a regional restriction. On the bottom right of the Google Maps page there is a country setting.

[image]

When it's changed to another country, for example Latvia, the feature becomes available.

Comment: in my case it was showing "GLOBAL", in the settings it was "Current Region" but  I found out that my current country (Monaco) is not even an option there! Picked France and list saving worked.

Comment: Kind of same in my case. It was initially showing "Global". Then I cnanged the region to "Azerbaijan". After reloading it was still showing "Global" and save didn't work. Then I changed the region to "current region". It was still showing "Global" and save didn't work. Then I changed the region to "Turkey" and it worked.

Comment: This regional restriction doesn't appear to be in the google maps app for android, thankfully I was able to keep adding to my list from my phone, and then it would sync and be available in my lists on the website-

Comment: Mine says "United States" why can't I create a list?