# Google Maps - Error Message "Failed to save to favorites"

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps, I try (for the first time) to save a location to the predefined "Favorites" list (under Menu > Your places > Saved > Favorites). I get the error message "Failed to save to favorites". Saving to the list "Starred places" is possible however. I am using the Browser version with Chrome under Windows 10. How can I get around this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create new lists and cannot save places to existing lists in Google Maps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113409/cannot-create-new-lists-and-cannot-save-places-to-existing-lists-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 1):

My Solution: I used the mobile app version of Google Maps (iOS). I added one place to the list "Favorites" which was possible without error message. After adding the first entry, it was also possible to add more places to the list with the browser version.

Remark: This question has already been asked in [Cannot create new lists and cannot save places to existing lists in Google Maps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113409/cannot-create-new-lists-and-cannot-save-places-to-existing-lists-in-google-maps). The answer given there (change the region) did not solve the problem for me.

Unfortunately, I could not answer that question due to lack of reputation, hence I am posting the same question again and answering it myself. Sorry for the duplicate but I didn't see any other way to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the Failed to save message by following these steps:

1. Open Your Places
2. Select LABELED or SAVED
3. Select the list where you want to add the address
4. Select the three vertical dots in the upper right corner
5. Select the list where you want to add the address
6. Select + Add a Place
7. Enter the address you want to save. It will search for that name or
   address and give you some choices
8. Select your choice and it should add it to your list

Hope that works for you